# How to set IP_MULTICAST_LOOP on multicast UDPConn in Golang

Tags: go, multicast, multicastsocket

I need to set IP_MULTICAST_LOOP on a multicast UDP connection/socket so I can send/receive multicast packets on my local machine. This is the call that I've found which should work:

```
l, err := net.ListenMulticastUDP("udp4", nil, addr)
file, err := l.File()
fd := syscall.Handle(file.Fd())

err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 1)
```

However it fails with "not supported by windows". I'm pretty sure this is supported by sockets in windows, just not in the Go net package. Any idea on how I can set this flag on my connection? (I'm new to the Go language, I may have overlooked something obvious). This is on Windows, I haven't had a chance to test on Linux.

Comment: For reference I'm using go 1.8 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ListenMulticastUDP) says, `net.ListenMulticastUDP` is just for convenience of simple small applications. You can use [golang.org/x/net/ipv4](http://golang.org/x/net/ipv4) for general purpose uses, this package offers you more options about multicast.. Actually, the source code of `net.ListenMulticastUDP()` sets `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP` to false:

```
func listenIPv4MulticastUDP(c *UDPConn, ifi *Interface, ip IP) error {
    if ifi != nil {
        if err := setIPv4MulticastInterface(c.fd, ifi); err != nil {
            return err 
        }   
    }   
    if err := setIPv4MulticastLoopback(c.fd, false); err != nil {
        return err 
    }   
    if err := joinIPv4Group(c.fd, ifi, ip); err != nil {
        return err 
    }   
    return nil 
}
```

`setIPv4MulticastLoopback()` is implemented for different OSes, and it's not exported. For Windows, it's in `sockoptip_windows.go`:

```
func setIPv4MulticastLoopback(fd *netFD, v bool) error {
    if err := fd.incref(); err != nil {
        return err 
    }   
    defer fd.decref()
    return os.NewSyscallError("setsockopt", syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd.sysfd, syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, boolint(v)))
}
```

Below is an example with `golang.org/x/net/ipv4`, you can get/set `MulticastLoopback`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
)

func main() {
    ipv4Addr := &net.UDPAddr{IP: net.IPv4(224, 0, 0, 251), Port: 5352}
    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp4", ipv4Addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ListenUDP error %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    pc := ipv4.NewPacketConn(conn)

    // assume your have a interface named wlan
    iface, err := net.InterfaceByName("wlan")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("can't find specified interface %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    if err := pc.JoinGroup(iface, &net.UDPAddr{IP: net.IPv4(224, 0, 0, 251)}); err != nil {
        return
    }

    // test
    if loop, err := pc.MulticastLoopback(); err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("MulticastLoopback status:%v\n", loop)
        if !loop {
            if err := pc.SetMulticastLoopback(true); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("SetMulticastLoopback error:%v\n", err)
            }
        }
    }

    if _, err := conn.WriteTo([]byte("hello"), ipv4Addr); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Write failed, %v\n", err)
    }


    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        if n, addr, err := conn.ReadFrom(buf); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error %v", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("recv %s from %v\n", string(buf[:n]), addr)
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: ok, so how do I set it to true in my own code, since it's not exported?

Comment: As the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ListenMulticastUDP) says,  `net.ListenMulticastUDP` is just for convenience of simple small applications. You can use [golang.org/x/net/ipv4](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv4#PacketConn.SetMulticastLoopback) for general purpose uses, this package offers you more options about multicast.

Comment: Do you have an example for how this is done? I've been trying to search and figure this out for a while.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I also learned that you can pass nil instead of the network interface so it'll listen on all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's kinda stupid that the stdlib ListenMulticastUDP disables loopback by default because it renders it completely useless for testing purposes (ie, running more than one node on a test machine) and it doesn't say clearly on the documentation that it specifically disables loopback, it's unjustified and annoying.

https://github.com/p9c/p9/blob/main/pkg/multicast/channel.go is a simple function that returns a standard 224.0.0.1 with an arbitrary port with loopback enabled. I suppose it would be even nicer if it let you pick the loopback address but for building LAN multicast IPv4 systems this is all you need.

Comment: the doc has been updated since.